# Timeout when attempting to connect to S3 bucket using boto on a python lambda function

Tags: python, boto, aws-lambda, boto3

I'm trying to write a fairly simple AWS lambda function that receives a creation event on an S3 bucket, cross-references that file against a database, and if the file is found to be of a certain type, copies it to another bucket. By configuring my VPC and assigning appropriate permissions to the role used in the lambda function I've had no trouble exporting a deployment file that includes `pymysql` and allows me to talk to the DB. Where I'm really getting hung up is on communicating with S3. The following code runs until printing `"base s3 connection successful"` before timing out. It times out whether I've set the timeout threshold to 30 seconds or 5 minutes.

I've tried manually creating the connection, as well as relying on the environmental variables supplied by the lambda environment with the same result. Is my problem related to using `boto` instead of `boto3`?

How do I fix this?

Cheers,

Aaron

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os
import json
import urllib
import boto3

import boto
from boto.s3.key import Key
import pymysql

print(os.environ)

import credentials
CRM_HOST = credentials.CRM_HOST
CRM_USER = credentials.CRM_USER
CRM_PASS = credentials.CRM_PASS
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = credentials.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = credentials.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

try:
    conn = pymysql.connect(host=CRM_HOST, user=CRM_USER,\
        passwd=CRM_PASS, db='oro_crm')
    print('SQL connection successful')
except Exception, e:
    print('SQL connection failed')
    print(str(e))

try:
    # s3 = boto.connect_s3(aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,\
    #     aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    s3 = boto.connect_s3()
    print('base S3 connection successful')
    src = s3.get_bucket('s3-crm-dev')
    print('got ocr source bucket')
    dst = s3.get_bucket('s3-crm-input')
    print('got ocr input bucket')
    out_dst = s3.get_bucket('s3-crm-output')
    print('got ocr output bucket')
```

Comment: If you are using Lambda within your VPC you will have to configure an S3 VPC endpoint, or use a NAT Gateway.

Comment: Can you explain to me super quickly how to configure a VPC endpoint for S3? This was straightforward for RDS, but I really struggled with this yesterday for S3.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-endpoint-for-amazon-s3/

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. I'm going to wait till the end of the day to configure the endpoint because it looks like it has the potential to affect communication between existing process and S3 resources, but I'm pretty sure this gets me what I need. @MarkB, if you want to write this up as a short answer I'll accept it.